# Join-style Merge using Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, merge, mapreduce

I working with a old school project running Hadoop to process MapReduce jobs and I'm currently stuck trying to get a join to work. I have 2 files, say:

File 1:

```
onion vegetable
potato vegetable
orange fruit
apple fruit
banana fruit
carrot vegetable
melon fruit
```

and the second file is
File 2:

```
1 apple
2 banana
3 carrot
4 orange
5 melon
6 onion
```

What I want is the indices of items which are vegetables, so expected items are:

```
3
6
```

I am unsure how to go about this. I've never worked with plainjane Hadoop before so I'm unsure if I'm missing something simple. Note that File 2 and File 1 can have entries that have no corresponding match in the other file.

Pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Hive, Pig or Spark?